# Settlers of Catan edition?

Tags: catan

I have a version of Settlers of Catan that I can't seem to figure out. It is a family edition, but doesn't match anything I can find online. I recently bought an expansion for the 5-6 players, but the pieces were too big for my smaller pieces to be compatible. I'd like to get an expansion that matches mine, but can't find anything other than 5th editions[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is no expansion for the Family Edition.

From the [Catan website](https://www.catan.com/game/catan-family-edition):

> This version of Catan is not expandable and not compatible with the regular expansions of the Catan base game!

You will need to get a regular edition (not family edition) of Catan to play with more than 4 players.

Comment: In my experience, Catan is more than a game, it's a game framework. Try exploring with what you have and see if it works out! Even if it doesn't work out it will be a cheap night of entertainment!

Comment: @corsiKa The Family Edition removes a lot of that possibility though. The hexes are not each separate pieces to allow for trying other things; there really isn't any way that you can physically combine the pieces from the 5-6 player expansion to accommodate more players.